# PHP string help mail

Tags: email, variables, phpmailer, php

hi need some help with mailing. I'm trying to insert the content of this variable into a string to send as an email also need to add a newline. Also need to change From header to "Procity" and procitystaff@gmail.com

```
$claim_msg='Hey $claim_username, \n The donator has cancelled your claimed item, but you got your          '    $email_to=$claim_email;
$template=$claim_msg;
$subject= "Claimed item canceled";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 '.' \r\n';
$headers .= 'From: procitystaff@gmail.com'.' \r\n';
$from='procitystaff@gmail.com';

mail($email_to,$subject,$template,$headers);
```

Comment: Why not use the [actual PHPMailer package you tagged in](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/phpmailer/info)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi-colon before `$email_to` which would cause a syntax error.

You're also using single-quotes `'` while inserting a php variable printing out `Hey $claim_username` as opposed to double-quotes `"` which would print `Hey JohnDoe`.

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon was missing at the end of the first line in the code below. Plus, I also used concatenates.

Give this a try. There will be a line break between the username and `The donator`.

#### Example:

Hey John,
The donator has cancelled your claimed item, but you got your

```
$claim_msg='Hey ' . $claim_username . ',' . "<br>\n" . 'The donator has cancelled your claimed item, but you got your';
$email_to=$claim_email;
$template=$claim_msg;
$subject= "Claimed item canceled";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 '.' \r\n';
$headers .= 'From: Procity <procitystaff@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$from='procitystaff@gmail.com';

mail($email_to,$subject,$template,$headers);
```